# Continuous beeping after selecting usb bootable drive

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb

I am trying to load the Windows 7 32-bit installer. I have made a bootable pendrive using [Rufus](http://rufus.ie/). In BIOS boot menu,

- USB Boot is Enabled
- UEFI Boot is Enabled and
- Boot to Removable Devices is Enabled.

On rebooting the PC, pressing the boot menu key, and selecting my bootable pendrive, a black screen appears with blinking cursor and continuous beeping sound. Nothing happens after this and beeping is continuous.

This is my motherboard and BIOS spec.

- Motherboard Intel [DH55TC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023741/boards-and-kits/desktop-boards.html)
- BIOS Version TCIBX10H.86A.0027.2009.1119.1517
- CPU Core i3-530
- RAM 4GB

Comment: Please update your BIOS from https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/42408/intel-desktop-board-dh55tc.html aas the current version for that 10 year old board is version 48. Updating other drivers is also recommended.